# get OID when debugging plain Java

Tags: java, debugging, oid

When debugging in Eclipse IDE (core Java) inspected objects are shown followed by an id, e.g.: 
myObject=MyClass (id=123)

For detecting unintended object changes it would be helpful to log any OIDs too.
Any idea how to write a getOid() method that returns an object specific unique ID? 
It needs not be serializable, it is just used within one run.
In contrast to hashCode() the OID must be unique.
This getOid() may return int, long, String or whatever printable.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe System.identityHashCode(Object x) is what you are looking for. As given by the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-), It prints out the same value as would be printed by the objects default hashCode(). This should be unique, as it is often the memory address for the object. In this case you could use the default hashCode() as well.

You could also override the hashCode() method using java.util.Objects.hash(Object... values) and passing in the fields of your object. This will verify for you that the internals of your object aren't changing.

However, are you trying to track the same internal ID as defined by Eclipse? I'm not positive, but I suspect that is assigned by the Eclipse debugger internally and is unavailable for you.

Comment: System.identityHashCode(Object x) does not return a unique value, it just guarantees the original hashCode() calculated by Object and not by a overriding hashCode() method.

Comment: The OID needs not be the same as the one in Eclipse - that changes from run to run anyway. It just needs to be specific to that object and unique.

Comment: What exactly is your purpose with this? If it is a specific object you are looking for, an alternative would be to assign a unique ID in the constructor of your object and check that.

Comment: The purpose is logging the OIDs for detecting if an

Comment: Let's say the object reference myObj pointed to obj1 first. Unintendedly later a new object is created:

Comment: myObj = new MyClass()  =>  logging myObj.getOid() twice will show the difference

Comment: If the reference is changed to point to a new object, the value returned by the default hashCode() method should change. Have you tried using the default hashCode() method? While it isn't guaranteed by its interface to be unique, to my knowledge most JVMs implement it as returning the memory address of the object so it should be different if the reference is pointing to a new/different object.

Comment: Your proposal "to assign a unique ID in the constructor" would work, e,g, by a timestamp System.nanos() or better by an autoincrementing sequence generator, but is not very comfortable - just for debugging.

Comment: Concerning to hashCode():  new String("123")==new String("123")  results in false because their physical address differs, although their hashCodes are the same - not unique. When added to a HashMap, both are added to the same bucket because their hashCode is the same. Otherwise HashMaps would not work.

Comment: That's because the String class's hashCode method has been overriden to hash based on the contents of the strings, i.e. Two Strings with the same contents will have the same hashCode. If you are working with your own objects, using the default hashcode method should work.

Comment: I would "like to automatically move this discussion to chat", but I do not have enough reputation points, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I solved it by a sequence generator 'OIDGenerator' used in all constructors:

public class OIDGenerator {
 private static OIDGenerator mOIDGen;
 private static long mOID;

 /**
  * Singleton Constructor
  */
 private OIDGenerator() {
  mOID = 0;
 }

 public static long longNext() {
  if( mOIDGen == null) {
   mOIDGen = new OIDGenerator();    // => init 0
  }
  return ++mOID;
 }

 public static String next() {
  return new StringBuffer( "@").append( String.valueOf( longNext())).toString();
 }
}
... Rest below ...

Comment: ... the rest:
Member variables in all classes:
 private final transient String mOID;
In their constructors:
 mOID = OIDGenerator.next();
Provided method:
 @Override
 public String getOID() {
  return mOID;
 }
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by a sequence generator 'OIDGenerator' used in all constructors:

public class OIDGenerator {

```
private static OIDGenerator mOIDGen;
private static long mOID;

/**
 * Singleton Constructor
 */
private OIDGenerator() {
    mOID = 0;
}

public static long longNext() {
    if( mOIDGen == null) {
        mOIDGen = new OIDGenerator();    // => init 0
    }
    return ++mOID;
}

public static String next() {
    return new StringBuffer( "@").append( String.valueOf( longNext())).toString();
}
```

}

Member variables in all classes:

```
private final transient String mOID;
```

In their constructors:

```
mOID = OIDGenerator.next();
```

Provided method:

```
@Override
public String getOID() {
    return mOID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The even simpler version without a OIDGenerator constructor:

public class OIDGenerator {

```
private static long sOID = 0;

public static long longNext() {
    return ++sOID;
}

public static String next() {
    return new StringBuffer( "@").append( String.valueOf( longNext())).toString();
}
```

}

But keep in mind that because of the static variable both versions can not be used in a cluster of servers.